# Eclipse CDT specify only some folders as resource

Tags: eclipse-cdt

In eclipse CDT 4.2 i want to include only few folders as resource.
eg "/root" is the place where project "myproject" is created. I want to include only these folders and exclude any others.

- /root/A
- /root/B
- /root/C/D

I am aware that this can be done in

```
   Project -> Resource -> Resource Filters
```

But the UI there is confusing me.

- What is the difference between Location and Relative path.
- The check box "Apply recursively" is also confusing me a bit.
- There is a way to  specify regular expression but if I put a regex starting with *, like  */root/A/* or */myproject/A/*  it will give error saying "Dangling meta character near index 0".

In short because of these seemingly confusing options (to me) I am not yet able to acheive above. Please clarify

PS :  The way source lies in linux my file system and proprietary source control system they all are links. Not sure if this matters , but just mentioning.

eg
root/A/file.c  -->  [link to version control system for file.c]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- What is the difference between Location and Relative path.

The Location is the full path (e.g. `/home/user123/workspcae/proj1/src/foo.c`), where relative path is only the part within the project directory (e.g. `src/foo.c`)

- The check box "Apply recursively" is also confusing me a bit.

Means the rule is not only used for the projet-root, but also for any sub-directory. I.e. a rule to match `src/*.c` won't do anything without "Apply recursivly", because it only matches files in the sub-directory `src`

- There is a way to specify regular expression but if I put a regex starting with *, like */root/A/* or */myproject/A/* it will give error saying "Dangling meta character near index 0".

You are using wildcards, not regular expressions. regex are much more complex, and stars mean the previous 'object' may occur zero or more times. Without this previous object Eclipse gets confused. Just don't check the regex-box and it should work as you expected, or add a dot before the star, meaning any character.

***To Solve your Problem do:***

> Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters

- Include only:

  - Folder: (name match) a
  - Folder: (name match) b
  - Folder: (name match) c
- Exclude all:

  - Files: (name match) *

> Folder c -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters

- Include only:

  - Folder: (name match) d
- Exclude all:

  - Files: (name match) *

Comment: Thanks. But if possible can you have a take at main question. ie Include folder /root/A/**, /root/B/**  but exclude every other folder  in root/   (i cant exclude other folders one by one using option given there, too many folders).

Comment: you don't have to exclude a folder if you already said include *only* folder a and b